# Android MaterialDatePicker layout problems

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm developing an app that needs to get the user's birthday,
I've already did it with DatePickerDialogFragment, but now I'm trying to do it with Material Design,
so I found a way to create a date picker dialog with this library:

```
private MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker;
...
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        builder.setTitleText(getResources().getString(R.string.birthday_it));
        builder.setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar);

        materialDatePicker = builder.build();
```

And then with a button I show it:

```
    birthdayButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
    });
```

There's no problem with this, indeed I can select my date etc, but on display it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/60sD8.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWEGW.png

As you can see from these two images, when i select a day the selector image is not aligned with the day number and then when I pass to dialog mode is still on the previous layout and doesn't wrap it.

What can I do? I searched but I didn't find anything for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your app theme to a [**Material Components Theme**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
   ....
</style>
```

Also `builder.setTheme(R.style.ThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialCalendar);` is not needed since it is the default theme.